# Handling an SQL Injection attack

Tags: sql-injection

What should an Incident Handler do (or) follow when an SQL injection attack is reported?

1. Initial Response
2. Analysis
3. Action

Aiming to make a Procedure guide to follow for myself and my team.
Brief or detail, anything would help.

Comment: Better suited for [Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Security.StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Not a full process, but it should get you started:

- Initial Response

  - Verify that the reported vulnerability is legitimate, preferably in a production-safe manner
  - See the [OWASP SQL Injection Testing guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-005)) for more information on how to do this
- Analysis

  - Determine the cause of the SQL Injection
  - This is probably a location where user input is directly concatenated into a SQL query
- Action

  - The best defense against SQL Injection is to utilize [parameterized/prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead of direct string concatenation when building a query based on user input.
  - These statements provide a clear divide between **data** and **syntax**, so that user input is never treated as SQL syntax but instead treated as data
  - How you do this will depend on the language and framework used in your application
  - See the [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more information on preventing SQL injection